# Who qualifies for free admission to the Louvre?

Tags: france, eu, paris, museums, the-louvre

I'm a student in Germany and I have a student visa but I don't have a residence permit yet. Am I eligible to get into the Louvre for free?

Answer (score 11):

Free admission to the Louvre is not based on student status but on age.

People residing in the EU can enter free if they are less than 26. For others it’s up to 18.

If you are between 18 and 26 you would need some ID giving your age and some proof that you are resident in the EU, so you’ll probably need to wait for your residency permit. Note that even if you qualify for free entry it is recommended to book your (free) ticket online.

Admission is also free after 6pm on the first Friday of each month, and all day on July 14th (unless that falls on a Tuesday).

Comment: When I (an American) was studying abroad in Italy. I managed to get in for free with a letter from the university saying I was studying in the EU. That means a student ID may suffice but YMMV

Comment: EU student card was accepted in my experience, for any museum in Paris.

Comment: OK, "unless that falls on a Tuesday" sounds like one of those bizarro, made-up rules that committees come up with...

Comment: @FreeMan: July 14th is the national holiday in France, so it makes sense for the Louvre to be free on that day. However, the Louvre is closed on Tuesdays. In this constellation, the "closed on Tuesdays" wins.

Comment: Ah, gotcha, thanks @StephanKolassa. I wondered about that, but didn't care to spend time looking up the Louvre's schedule, and my version was more entertaining (at least to me).